# Two monitors: intel VGA + Nvidia DVI

Tags: debian, xorg, nvidia, multi-monitor, intel-graphics

Recently I've bought a [GA-Z87-HD3 motherboard](http://www.gigabyte.com/products/product-page.aspx?pid=4489#sp) and a [GTX 660 graphics card](http://www.nvidia.it/object/geforce-gtx-770-it.html).

Now I have two monitors, the first that I'm using is attached to the DVI port of the Nvidia graphic card, the second one is attached on the VGA port of the embedded graphic card of the motherboard.

Since I would like to play a little with Blender, I need to use two monitors at the same time because in this way I can watch better more video tutorials at the same time.

I'm using Debian wheezy:

```
#uname -a
Linux ziomario-Z87-HD3 3.2.0-4-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 3.2.60-1+deb7u1 x86_64 GNU/Linux
# lspci -nn | grep VGA
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Intel Corporation Haswell Integrated Graphics Controller [8086:0412] (rev 06)
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: NVIDIA Corporation Device [10de:11c0] (rev a1)
```

So please can someone help me to use my two monitors together?

Comment: Maybe it would be better to use a DVI-to-VGA adapter then use a single video card for both displays? Otherwise, is Xinerama still a thing? That's how we used to do multiple monitors with multiple video cards as one user in the old days.

Answer (score 0):

Check this out, I followed the steps and got 2 users, one on each screen.

But I couldn't manage to have accelerated graphics on my intel vga.

I used lightdm as desktop manager. gdm3 does not have many options and gdm is unfortunately obsolete.

[Hardware Accelerated NVidia and Intel Graphics Together in Debian](http://blog.startupanywhere.org/hardware-accelerated-nvidia-and-intel-graphics-together-in-debian/)